# Tamaki's reasoning for making Haruhi a host?

Tags: ouran-high-school-host-club

In the anime series 'Ouran High School Host Club' what's Tamaki's reasoning behind making Haruhi a host?

If she had continued on as an errand boy, the debt would have been paid off eventually... even if it took years.

The hosts don't charge any of their customers, and even if they did... Tamaki tells Haruhi she only needs to get 100 customers for her debt to be erased, and unless they were charging a fortune 100 customers wouldn't even come close to paying off her debt.

So, what's in this deal for Tamaki? At the time of the 100 customer arrangement he's not attracted to her, he still thinks she's a boy. So it can't be that he just wants to keep her around.

Is it a personal challenge for Tamaki to see if he can train the "commoner" well enough to get 100 customers?

What's his reasoning?

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it, Tamaki doesn't care about money at all. He started the host club merely as a form of entertainment for himself. When he noticed how good Haruhi looked (even in "male" form) he decided that adding "him" to the club would only make things even more interesting. While I have found nothing to actually support any of this, it's something that I believe is a very plausible answer.

Answer (score 1):

Haruhi is made to join the Host club as its "dog" after breaking the vase. They were all initially just going to use her as an "errand boy" since she was just a commoner, and they used fear and power over her to do this. After giving her a uniform to wear, so that she would be dressed appropriately, Tamaki becomes so enamored with how she looks that he decides to move her up in rank, making her an official member of the club, a host, as well as changing the terms of her debt repayment.